# MergeSort without merge function,, How does this algorithm merges the lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, mergesort

```
def mergeSort(A):
    if len(A) < 2:
        return A

    mid = int(len(A)/2)
    left = mergeSort(A[:mid])
    right = mergeSort(A[mid:])

    r,l = 0,0
    B = []

    while len(B) < len(A):
        if r >= len(right) or (l < mid and left[l] < right[r]):
            B.append(left[l])
            l += 1
        elif r < len(right):
            B.append(right[r])
            r += 1

    return B

print(mergeSort([4,3,6,9,8,5,1]))
```

My doubt in the above program is how the lists are merged without a separate merge function?

After the recursive function calls in the end I think `left` and `right` lists contain only one element each... they are sorted and inserted in to list `B` using a `while` loop... what about other elements.. because here `while` loop is executed only once and how the list `A` is again split and merged...I got this program in internet and it works perfectly fine.

Comment: Do you see that `while` loop? That's the merge. It doesn't need to be a separate function.

Comment: "After the recursive function calls in the end I think left and right lists contain only one element each" - well, that's not the case. I have no idea why you think that's true.

Comment: yes while loop will merge the lists but after the recursive function calls all the elements of the list will become individual elements.. and then they are merged back

Comment: Try working through the code on paper, stepping through it in the debugger, using a graphical visualizer like [this one](http://goo.gl/Ln5XAu), or just adding a bunch of `print` calls. It's a lot easier than trying to reason about it from the cloud level. (Put a breakpoint at line 12 or skip ahead to step 31 to see the first non-trivial merge operation.)

Comment: List B is declared out the while loop and while loop doing the job. But a = [4,3,6,9,8,5,1] print sorted(a, key=int)  this will do the same function

Comment: look at 2nd and 3rd line in the code,,, why is it used,,,, after recursive calls LEFT and RIGHT list contains only one element

Comment: @Achayan: First, no it won't, it'll do a timsort, which is a modified merge sort that is not the same as this algorithm. Second, what's the point of `key=int` when the values are already ints?

Comment: @shrinidhikulkarni: At the base level of the recursion, yes, you have either 1- or 0-length lists, and those are "merged" trivially. The interesting part is what happens at the next level up, to merge together two 1-length lists, and the level above that, to merge together two longer lists.

Comment: @Achayan, Problem is not in while loop. My doubt is in recursion in above program

Comment: @abarnert  This is exactly my question

Comment: as @abarnert said if you try to visualize the algorithm then you will understand I think. Its trying to find the first, mid and last value using the recursion. After that its building the return value.

Comment: @abarnert if the mid after calculation is float it takes only integer

Comment: @shrinidhikulkarni: First, in your code, it would probably be better to use `// 2` instead of `/ 2` and `int(…)`. But I was referring to Achayan's code, which calls `int` on each of the elements of the list, which are already ints in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is that you don't understand how recursion works. The while loop isn't only executed once, it's executed once *per (non-trivial) recursive call*.

It's worth tracing through the operation. Whether you do it on paper, in the debugger, using a graphical visualizer like [this one](http://goo.gl/Ln5XAu), or just by using a bunch of `print` calls, it's the only way you're really going to understand exactly what's going on.

I think the graphical visualizer will be easier to follow, but learning how to do it on paper is worthwhile, so let's do that. We only need to step through one of the non-trivial merges, because after that they all look the same.

- Sort `[4,3,6,9,8,5,1]`

  - Sort `[4,3,6]`
  - Sort `[4]`
  - Because `[4]` has length 0 or 1, trivially sort it by just returning it as-is.
  - Sort `[3, 6]`
  - Sort `[3]`

    - Because `[3]` has length 0 or 1, trivially sort it by just returning it as-is.
  - Sort `[6]`

    - Because `[6]` has length 0 or 1, trivially sort it by just returning it as-is.
  - Merge the sorted `[3]` and `[6]` halves (if you're using the graphical visualizer, this happens at step 31; if using the debugger, put a breakpoint at line 12 and this will be the first time the breakpoint is hit):

    - Start with `l, r, B = 0, 0, []`
    - Since `len([]) < len([3, 6])`, we're not done.
    - Since the first `if` condition is true, append from `left` and increment `l`, so `l, r, B = 1, 0, [3]`.
    - Since `len([3]) < len([3, 6])`, we're not done.
    - Since the first `if` condition is false and the second is true, append from `right` and increment `r`, so `l, r, B = 1, 1, [3, 6]`.
    - Since `len([3, 6]) == len([3, 6])`, we're done.
  - Merge the sorted `[4]` and `[3, 6]` halves the same way as above.
- Sort `[9, 8, 5, 1]`.

  - This goes the same as the above, and will include trivially returning 4 single-element lists, plus using the `while` loop to merge `[9]` and `[8]`, and `[5]` and `[1]`, and `[8, 9]` and `[1, 5]` along the way; you can step through the details yourself if you don't understand how that works.
- Merge the sorted `[3, 4, 6]` and `[1, 5, 8, 9]` halves the same way as above.

As you can see, the while loop is actually executed six times, not just once.

Comment: @abarnert..I was just tracing the program... You said..Merge the sorted [4] and [3, 6] halves the same way as above.. I am not getting how come control  goes above while loop.. Can u please eleborate

Comment: @shrinidhikulkarni: I'm not going to step through all 181 steps manually. I gave you a link to an online graphical visualizer, explained how to do this with the debugger, and demonstrated how to do it manually if you want to. You have to pick at least one of those and actually do it yourself, and step through until you understand.

Comment: @shrinidhikulkarni: Yes, that's it. The inner call returns to an outer call that has its own while loop, and returns to an even-more-outer call that has its own, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Before the while loop is executed, we have two sorted lists in `left` and `right`
what the while loop does is go through each elements in the lists `left` and `right` sequentially and insert the smaller elements into an empty list `B`, and it is returned by mergesort function.

we need not call a merge function separately

for example, consider list [3,1,2]
the calls will be:

```
mergesort([3,1,2])
left = mergesort([3]) -> [3]
right = mergesort([1,2]) -> [1,2] #magically

B = []
```

the while loop picks the `l`th/`r`th element of left/right depending on which one is smaller, and increments l/r respectively, and inserts that element into B

```
B -> [1,2,3]
```

try running the while loop for mergesort([1,2]) on paper to understand how `right` becomes [1,2]

Comment: There is no seperate merge function here.. The interesting part is what happens at the next level up, to merge together two 1-length lists, and the level above that, to merge together two longer lists.